# Выплывающее модальное окно при входе на сайте

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте, как сделать всплывающие модальное окно при входе на сайте? Например, как на  ruseller.com - оно там всплывает через 3 сек при входе на сайт.

**Добавлено.**

У меня плагин fancybox, вызываю страницы так

```
$("#various3").fancybox({
    'width': '100%',
    'height': '100%',
    'autoScale': false,
    'transitionIn': 'none',
    'transitionOut': 'none',
    'type': 'iframe'
});
```

и

```
<a id="various3" href="http://google.ru">google</a>
```

Как в этом случае гугл запускать автоматом при заходе на сайт?

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(open_modal, 3000);
function open_modal(){
    // показать окно
}
```

Comment: у меня планиг fancybox  вызываю страницы так  
$("#various3").fancybox({
'width':'100%',
'height':'100%',
'autoScale':false,
'transitionIn':'none',
'transitionOut':'none',
'type':'iframe'
});
<a id="various3" href="http://google.ru">google</a>  
как в этом случаи гугл запускать автоматом при заходе на сайт?

Comment: function open_modal(){
        $.fancybox({...});
    }

Либо же

    $("#various3").fancybox({...}).click();

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы окошко было красивое рекомендую jQuery библиотеки, такие как  [colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) или [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/). В первом случае имеется поддержка iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. окно на jquery, то важно чтобы он был готов уже, поэтому

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(open_modal, 3000);
    function open_modal(){
     // показать окно
    }

});
```